# Sharing for Facebook in Unity Example

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I was checking for some tutorials how to implement Share button for Unity games. I want to share my game with custom picture, text and link together with my description over the share automatically.

I found this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/sharing

but I am not sure if this thing even works anymore. I found somewhere that I have to create custom HTML file with all og metadata inside in order to work this through. I tried that too, but when I press share button, Facebook automatically scrapes data from my website and not custom HTML file. In Unity I have initialized everything correctly, so there should not be problem in initialization, I guess something is either wrong in my code or in Facebook side.

Can someone share simle example how can I make HTML file connected to my unity game in order to correctly share custom data (Title, description, image....) like on link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/sharing

Kindly appreciate it.

Best regards